# Does the notion of Mellin transform make sense for complex functions as well?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, definition, mellin-transform

In most of the sources I looked regarding the Mellin transform, 
they say let $f$ be a  function  defined  on  the  positive  real  axis  $0  <  t  <  \infty$. And then say the Mellin transform is 
$$
M(f;s) = \int_0^{\infty} f(t) t^{s-1} dt.  
$$
And all the examples I have seen is where $f$ is a real function. 
I was just wondering does the notion make sense for $f$ is a complex function as well?
and people use it? thank you.